# How to import Qr-Code for logging in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need good example about QR-Code scanner , read the data from the code and pass for checking? I don't know how to do it. I have a button for scan:

```
        <StackLayout Spacing="10" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" >
            <Button Text="Scan your QR-code"  BackgroundColor="#006BE6" CornerRadius="10 "
                x:Name="scanButton"  TextColor="WhiteSmoke"
                Command="{Binding ScanQrCodeCommand}"/>

        </StackLayout>
```

Now in ScanQrCodeCommand i need to scan with the camera and get the data from the code and pass to my service for check login? How to do this

Comment: @Chetan Rawat maybe add some solution, not just simple edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to Zxing Barcode Library. it will Solves your Problem.

https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile

tutorial here if you wish :

https://julianocustodio.com/2017/11/03/scanner/